# How to connect Docker Machine to a remote Docker VirtualBox

Tags: deployment, docker, remote-access, boot2docker

I'm trying to use Docker Machine to connect to a Docker VirtualBox VM on a different host. At my local host, the setup is successful, including examples installing Busybox and echo a 'hello world' from a VM called 'dev', like this:

> $ docker $(docker-machine config dev) run busybox echo hello world

I can create as many comparable local Docker VirtualBox VMs I like with Docker Machine and the result is similar succesful.

Now I would like to do the same using my local Docker Machine and execute docker commands on a different physical host where I installed Docker Machine and Boot2Docker as well. In other words: I would like to use my local Docker Machine CLI and remotely command to e.g. pull an image and run a container on that different host. Is that possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested with dind (Docker-in-Docker) here is the [link](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/) 
So all you have to do is run this in your host:
Docker Host IP: 172.17.42.1

1. docker run --rm swarm create #get cluster_id
2. docker run --privileged -d -p 1234:1234 -e PORT=1234 jpetazzo/dind
3. docker -H tcp://DOCKER_HOST:1234 run -d swarm join --addr=DOCKER_HOST:1234 token://cluster_id

you can create another node by

4. docker run --privileged -d -p 1235:1235 -e PORT=1235 jpetazzo/dind
5. docker -H tcp://DOCKER_HOST:1235 run -d swarm join --addr=DOCKER_HOST:1235 token://cluster_id
6. docker run -d -p 2375:2375 swarm manage token://cluster_id

Check is everything OK
docker -H tcp://DOCKER_HOST:2375 info

If you see 2 container, you are successfully created swarm cluster and docker machines as docker container.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done. For your local machine installation to be able to connect to a machine, it has to be the one to create that machine so that it can keep track of TLS certs and other connection details.

The VBox driver is meant to be used on your localhost. While drivers like the one for digitalocean is meant to create a VM on digitalocean where you can run containers.

If you really want to get this to work you could try to create a wrapper that uses SSH to execute commands on the other computer, other than that you are out of luck.

Machine is intended to be used as a docker host provisioner. It creates servers that are ready to run docker containers.

Comment: To support such a remote provisioning scenario, would Docker Swarm support that?

Comment: Swarm is a virtual interface that will delegate your docker commands between several docker hosts, you can run it against any docker host, if it runs on digitalocean, EC2, or VBox has no difference as long as swarm can connect, same goes for the normal docker client. So if you publish the docker daemon on a TCP socket you can connect to it with your laptop, or with swarm.

Comment: Thanks for the reflection. I used Docker Machine to create a Docker VM on a different 'minion' host and did a port forward from VirtualBox to the secured Docker port (2376). I copied the Docker Machine credentials (the .client .pem files) to the 'manager' host. Seems I can now access the Docker environment remotely including the credentials as arguments and do remote commands.